# Qt - How to create a blank area which holds 0 or more floating windows

Tags: c++, qt

I want to create an IDE in Qt. Is it possible to have in my main window a blank area which may contain 0 or more floating sub-windows (editor windows). Windows can be moved, resized, maximized and minimized, but always are limited to that area. Something like this:

https://www.google.co.il/search?q=editor+window&client=ubuntu&hs=bVx&channel=fs&dcr=0&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjzpeKgksTYAhUMORQKHXRaArgQ_AUICigB&biw=1535&bih=800#imgrc=FBAug3QGecw2WM:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`QMdiArea`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmdiarea.html) as the main window's central widget. This can have multiple `QMdiSubWindow`s, which are effectively independent windows. They can be allowed to resize, minimize, maximize, etc inside the MDI area, by calling `QMdiArea::cascadeSubWindows()`.

Comment: QMdiArea Is the trick.. you can find the example at : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-mainwindows-mdi-example.html

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks.